# IntelliJ IDEA 12 Keep Blank Lines

Tags: intellij-idea, reformat, blank-line, reformatting

I have this code:

```
private int a;

private int b;

private int c;
```

But when I reformat it with IntelliJ, it changes to this:

```
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;
```

How would I allow it to keep the blank lines?

But this code:

```
private boolean a;
private String s;
```

Should stay as it is.

Comment: You can use [Eclipse Code Formatter](http://plugins.jetbrains.net/plugin/?webide&pluginId=6546).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is caused by the Rearranger bug, at the moment it doesn't honor the maximum blank lines setting. I've created the [issue that you can follow for progress](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99782).

Comment: I should've been more specific in the original post, that option will apply blank lines around all fields. I do not want this. I would like it so if there already is a blank line between fields leave it there.

Comment: In this case change the first option instead (**Keep Maximum Blank Lines**, **In declarations**), use some larger value so that IDEA doesn't remove blank lines, for example values `1` or `2` will leave the provided sample code untouched.

Comment: Please zip and share a sample project with the embedded code style that will reproduce this problem with reformat in IDEA 12.0.2.

Comment: http://up.ht/SHFd2F

When reformatting that code the line breaks between the field groups get removed. I do not want that and I don't want to break the field groups up either.

Comment: Not reproducible for me with the default code style settings, rename [IDEA folders](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) to start with all the defaults and see if the issue remains. It can be caused by some third-party plug-in or corrupted configuration.

Comment: It works with default configuration and system settings o.O I'll change a few things and keep testing to find what's doing it :p

Comment: I found out it's something to do with my custom keymap :S When I use default it works otherwise it doesn't :(

It seems to be the keyboard shortcut to "Reformat Code". When I use the shortcut it removes all blank lines but if I right click the file it works :S

Comment: It seems to be the new Rearrange Code. Here is how I am rearranging the code : http://puu.sh/1Snd3

Comment: Updated the answer, it's a bug.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is there a workaround for this bug? My work install exhibits the problem, while my home install do *not*. I tried importing my home settings, but it didn't change anything. Both have the latest version (12.1.2).